# RelationshipGroups Managed Package App ver1.1 on SF Classic Production Org. SF is deprecating the old API Version. What will be the impact on our org?

Tags: api, managed-package, salesforce-classic

There is a Package named RelationshipGroups installed on our Salesforce Classic Org the version is 1.1. This is a Managed Package. The Salesforce API Version of the Package is 11.0. The installed packages are no longer available in the Salesforce App Exchange and cannot be upgraded (they have never been upgraded since installation). The Org is Salesforce Classic and no plans yet to move to Lightning.

The Package consists of S-Control, Button or Link, Apex Class, Apex trigger, Page Layout, Custom field, Custom Object, Tab.

Salesforce is deprecating the old API Version.

Just wanted to confirm and clarify,,, What will be the impact on our org (Salesforce Classic)?

I saw a knowledge article Salesforce Platform API Versions 21.0 through 30.0 Retirement.

This retirement does not include Custom Apex Rest and SOAP Web Services, Apex Class, Apex Triggers, or VF Pages.

Kindly help to confirm what is the impact on our Classic Org.

Thank you in advance for your response.

Answer (score 0):

As long as it doesn't call an old API version, you'll be fine (e.g. using the [AJAX Toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.ajax.meta/ajax/sforce_api_ajax_introducing.htm)). If it does, those features will stop working permanently when the deprecation occurs. You'll need to look at your S-Control source code and static resources (if any) to see if you're impacted. Unfortunately, you might need to get a developer involved to see if you're affected and/or migrate the UI to a newer technology. The Apex and so on would still work, though.